# Parse multiple XML although not all files have the elements with python

Tags: python, xml

this is my code, and i have some problem..

```
from xml.dom import minidom
openFiles = 'myxml/*.xml'

list = []

for xmlfiles in glob.glob(openFiles):
    doc = minidom.parse(xmlfiles)
    root = doc.getElementsByTagName("info")[0]
    project_name = root.getAttribute('project_name')
    list.append(project_name)
    ....
```

This code is working properly. But somehow because I run to open multiple files its error. The cause is because not all files that have 'info' elements. So is there a way to make it keep run and change it to 'none'?

So example become like this

project1, project2, none, project3, none

Sorry for my bad english, and thank you in advance

Comment: Either: 1. `try` and handle the error; or 2. Check that `doc.getElementsByTagName("info")` has provided a list before you try to index it. Your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the `try...except` handling according to the common Python coding principle EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission) and if there are no `'info'` element in XML, exception will be handled and `None` will be added to the list:

```
for xmlfiles in glob.glob(openFiles):
    doc = minidom.parse(xmlfiles)
    root = None
    try:
        root = doc.getElementsByTagName('info')[0]
    except IndexError:
        list.append(None)
    if root:
        project_name = root.getAttribute('project_name')       
        list.append(project_name)
    ....
```

Or you could use LBYL (Look before you leap) coding principle and check that `'info'` is in XML before getting its attribute:

```
for xmlfiles in glob.glob(openFiles):
    doc = minidom.parse(xmlfiles)
    if len(doc.getElementsByTagName('info')):
        root = doc.getElementsByTagName('info')[0]
        project_name = root.getAttribute('project_name')       
        list.append(project_name)
    else:
        list.append(None)
```

Comment: You break both of the basic principles of error handling here: 1. You have code in the `try` block that you *don't* anticipate errors from; and 2. You don't handle the specific exception you anticipate (bare `except` [is considered bad practice](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/)).

Comment: Added exception IndexError

Comment: That's half of it. Also, note that your second example has a somewhat unusual `if: except:` structure. Please test before answering.